# Pandas iterrows get row string as list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in pandas which looks like:

```
id  name  values

1    a    cat dog
2    b    bird fly
```

I'm currently doing:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print row["values"]
```

However, that prints the entire cell: `"cat dog"` or `"bird fly"`.

I've tried doing:

```
print row["values"][0]
```

That instead prints a single character, so `"c"` and `"b"`.

How can I get instead something like `["cat", "dog"]` and `["bird", "fly"]`

Comment: [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: `values` is a reserved term in Pandas, and you'll get unexpected output if you try and do operations on `df.values`.  Consider renaming that column.

Comment: You want `df['values'].str.split().tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print(row["values"].split())
```

Output:

```
['cat', 'dog']
['bird', 'fly']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the data

```
df['values'].str.split()

0     [cat, dog]
1    [bird, fly]
```

To get the individual element,

```
df['values'].str.split().str[0]
```

And you get

```
0     cat
1    bird
```